# PHP curl() Response to Associative Array

Tags: php, json, curl

I have recently started working with the PHP `curl()` function and I am trying to convert my retrieved JSON object to an associated array. Can anybody point me in the right direction? Thanks!

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("https://canvas.instructure.com/api/v1/courses?access_token=7~8SXvaXHjMFZFHAdU5yU0pxNmVwAj40sjW7jRHw1Bvzq09QTFWrJRFxTu4pHAqSZU");
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

The response:

```
[{"account_id":81259,"course_code":"CS50","default_view":"feed","id":870674,"name":"CS50","start_at":"2014-08-05T18:29:18Z","end_at":null,"public_syllabus":false,"storage_quota_mb":250,"apply_assignment_group_weights":false,"calendar":{"ics":"https://canvas.instructure.com/feeds/calendars/course_6QRRvAKDngrrXtTBhzCA5Oz46g3aLgfRt7PNH0NN.ics"},"enrollments":[{"type":"student","role":"StudentEnrollment","enrollment_state":"active"}],"hide_final_grades":false,"workflow_state":"available"}]
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to capture the result in a string, which is what you pass to `json_encode`.  I think you're passing `$ch` to `json_decode` which is not what you want. (As the error message states, `$ch` is a resource and `json_decode` expects to be passed a string).

```
$ch = curl_init("https://canvas.instructure.com/api/v1/courses?access_token=7~8SXvaXHjMFZFHAdU5yU0pxNmVwAj40sjW7jRHw1Bvzq09QTFWrJRFxTu4pHAqSZU");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// ...
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// $response will be false if the curl call failed
if($response) {
    var_dump(json_decode($response, true));
}
```

See [`curl_setopt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) documentation for more information.

Comment: Awesome! How come this doesn't print out though? `if($response) {
    $array = var_dump(json_decode($response, true));
    echo "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@";
    echo $array[0]['account_id'];
}`

Comment: if you're assigning the return results of `json_decode`, remove the `var_dump`.  I only put that in for illustration purposes.